# can not click the element which from[display:none] to [display:block] (bootstrap datatimepicker)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a page which has a bootstrap DateTime picker like this:

[image]

I can click the calendar icon to show the popup. Also, the popup becomes `display: block;` from `display: none;`

But when I click `今日` button,I got an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

But as you see the element is actually visible now.

My element selector is right, because I can log the element use:

```
eml = browser.find_element_by_class_name('today')
print eml.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

It shows `今日`

How can I click this element?

Comment: do you really need click on the calendar? because if you need just introduce a data you can select the previous checkbox and do a command send_keys("your_data")

Comment: the calendar can't support send keys, because it can only choose by click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try with action classes.

```
 Actions actions= new Actions(driver); // heare you state ActionBuider
actions.moveToElement(eml); // Here you perform hover mouse over the needed elemnt to triger the visibility of the hidden
actions.click().build().perform();
```

I think this should work.Please let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: I add code like this `webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(eml).click(eml).perform()`, it have no error log, but it isn't click that element, I don't know why

Comment: Can you please paste the html code for webelement here . Also can you please check whether it is an svg element or something like that

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have no source code of this page, I only know that it a bootstrap datatimepicker component, but I think it's not a svg element.